# (Kendo UI, Angular) Pie Chart will not center

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

My markup is as follows:

```html
<div id="severity-piechart">
  <div ng-controller="SingleDetailsPieCtrl">
    <div kendo-chart k-theme="'metro'" k-title="{ text: 'All Issues', positon: 'top' }" 
      k-series-defaults="{ type: 'pie', 
                           labels: { 
                             visible: true, 
                             background: 'transparent', 
                             template: '#= category #: \n #= value#' 
                           } }"
      k-series=" [{ data: [{category: 'Issues', value: 14, color: '#FF0044'},
                           {category: 'Warnings', value: 4, color: '#FFD023'},
                           {category: 'Messages', value: 2, color: '#0B6FE8'}],
                 }]"
      k-legend="{ visible: false }"
      style="height: 35vh" >
    </div>                         
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I try the example located [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/angular) I can do whatever I want to the chart as long as I touch the style attribute. However when I do the same in this example:

```html
<div id="severity-piechart">
  <div ng-controller="SingleDetailsPieCtrl">
    <div kendo-chart k-theme="'metro'" k-title="{ text: 'All Issues', positon: 'top' }"
         k-series-defaults="{ type: 'pie', 
                              labels: { visible: true, background: 'transparent', 
                                        template: '#= category #: \n #= value#' } }"
         k-series=" [{data: [{category: 'Issues', value: 14, color: '#FF0044'},
                             {category: 'Warnings', value: 4, color: '#FFD023'},
                             {category: 'Messages', value: 2, color: '#0B6FE8'}],
                      }]"
         k-legend="{ visible: false }"
         style="height: 35vh; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; display: block;" >
    </div>                         
  </div>
</div>
```

The chart becomes incredibly small, it's not centered, and all of the labels are clipped.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Comment: You need to use `k-options` to set up the `chartArea` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for this, this was the answer.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it works out :)